Unable to add more "if" statements in Excel Formula
I have data where the "Frequency" is defined in Columns N as weeks or months, and "last completed date" in Column M. The frequencies are:
1 Week, 2 Weeks, 1 month, 3 months, 6 months, 12 months, 24 months, 36 months, 84 months
I need to add the corresponding frequency to my last completed date. If "months" are being added - than I need the last day of the month. I have the formula as:
=IF(J2="1 week",K2+7,IF(J2="2 weeks",K2+14,IF(J2="1 month",EOMONTH(EDATE(K2,1),0),IF(J2="3 months",EOMONTH(EDATE(K2,3),0),IF(J2="6 months",EOMONTH(EDATE(K2,6),0),IF(J2="12 months",EOMONTH(EDATE(K2,12),0),IF(J2="24 months",EOMONTH(EDATE(K2,24),0),IF(J2="36 months",EOMONTH(EDATE(K2,36),0),if(J2="84 months",eomonth(K2,84),0),if(or(J2="",K2=""),"Frequency or date not known","Entry Error")))))))))
Excel is generating "Too many arguments" error - the formula works if i delete the last 2 if statements (unless i'm coding the if(or) incorrectly)....is there a way around this?

This part eomonth(K2,84),0) breaks your formula. Missing EDATE part I believe

ah - you're right. I fixed that bit. I'm still struggling with K2 - if K2 is blank, I need it to say "frequency or date not known. Its not working. Ideas?

=IF(OR(J2:K2=""),"Frequency or date not known",LET(z,TEXTSPLIT(J2," "),IF(LEFT(TAKE(z,,-1))="w",K2+7*TAKE(z,,1),EOMONTH(EDATE(K2,TAKE(z,,1)),0))))

@ScottCraner - that's just amazing. Thanks!! If i read that right - if the first letter is "W", figure out the number, and multiply by 7. First letter is "M", figure out the number, and add that month to the date. Brilliant.

For the love of god do not use nested IFs.  Use SWTICH or if you have a newer version of Excel you can use `IFS'

Very similar to what Scot and Michal have suggested:
With Excel 2021 and later
=LET(
    j2_, J2,
    k2_, K2,
    j2_count, --LEFT(j2_, FIND(" ", j2_) - 1),
    completed_date, IFS(
        (j2_ = "") + (k2_ = ""),
        "Frequency or date not known",
        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("week", j2_)),
        k2_ + j2_count * 7,
        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("month", j2_)),
        EOMONTH(EDATE(k2_, j2_count), 0),
        TRUE,
        "Entry Error"
    ),
    completed_date
)

